# OCamllex syntax error

Tags: ocaml, lexer, ocamllex

When defining some identifiers in the definition section of my lexer (as described at [here](http://plus.kaist.ac.kr/~shoh/ocaml/ocamllex-ocamlyacc/ocamllex-tutorial/sec-ocamllex-format-of-the-input-file.html)), i'm trying to write something of the form:

```
    let op_char = ['+' '-' '*' '/']
    let id_char = [^ ' ' '\r' '\n' '\t' op_char]
```

To define id_char as every char not being a blank char or an op_char. However, i get a syntax error on "op_char" on the second line. How should I write this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let id_char = [^ ' ' '\r' '\n' '\t'] # op_char
```

See [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lexyacc.html#sec274).